# how to select grid columns by query button in telerik radgrid?

Tags: autocomplete, telerik, ria, radgrid

hello friends
i am displaying data in telerik radgrid and i want to add a autocomplete text box with query button to select the particular row using one column for binding.

Can any one provide me a hint?
it has been almost a complete day but im getting no help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the solution from [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/webmailgrid/defaultcs.aspx)? There is a textbox in the command item which filters the records by specified column values (the column is chosen from a dropdown beside the textbox).

Comment: i am using silverlight and telerik control for grid.can you provide solution for that?